# Extract pitch of wav file in C

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing, pitch

I'm trying to extract pitch of each frame of a wav file (music). I'm using [libsnd](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) for reading wav files. I'm open to use other libraries as well

I did a bit research and found out we can write a script using snack library to extract pitch files using wavsurfer. Snack library is available in C ([link](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/man/snack2.0/SnackLib.html%22link%22))but I don't think we can extract pitch from that library.

My final aim is to port this library to android. So if there is a library which is already ported to android, it will be of great use

Answer (score 0):

From a quick skim of the [snack manual](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/man/snack2.2/python-man.html) it appears you would use the `pitch` method of the sound object to extract pitch information. I have no idea if snack has been ported to Android. If not, you'd need to put some significant effort into that. It may be far easier to implement a [pitch detection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm) yourself. Snack's pitch method is documented to use [AMDF](http://sound.eti.pg.gda.pl/student/eim/synteza/leszczyna/index_ang.htm#a5).

When building a DTMF (aka touch tones) detector once in the dark past, I believe we used FFT over sample packets and binned the results to look for near matches to the centers of the tone frequencies. But DTMF was designed to be easy to detect.

Music transcription is likely to be another animal entirely, and easily confounded by the harmonic content of instrumental voices.

Answer (score 0):

[aubio](https://github.com/dafx/aubio) implements a couple of pitch estimation algorithms. It is mostly plain C code, so porting to other OS/CPU is trivial, as long as you don't care about performance.

Also have a look at [Sonic Visualizer](http://www.sonicvisualiser.org/). It visualises a lot of the audio features.

Comment: aubio was not very accurate. pYIN was better at doing this. Easiest way: get pYIN from soundsoftware and use the vamp-simple-host provided in the VAMP SDK as a starting point.